# Order By (alias) then Order by second sequalize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js, psql

I am using sequalize.js, I am having trouble with an order statement, I want to first order by if id (if my id is inside that alias table), then another order....

```
order = [['alias', 'id'], /*[this order statement already works]*/]
include = [    
      {
          model: model.aliasTable,
          as: 'alias'
      }
]
//['alias', 'id'] this is what is not working in my order statement
```

Answer (score 0):

try `order: [['alias', 'DESC'], ['id', 'DESC']]`

Comment: I need to include the second order by in there too though
```  [ ['alias', 'DESC'], ['id', 'DESC'],[this order statement already works]]```

Comment: can you show your second order statement?
another way to order by multiple columns is: `order: [[sequelize.literal('alias, id'), 'desc']]`

Comment: Its not super relevant to this order statement, it comes from another table

Comment: [Sequelize.literal(`(CASE WHEN "tblname"."colname" then 1 WHEN ("user"."status" = false) ASC`)] something like that